# growth rate of the sides of a triangle

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I got into this problem:

> In an isosceles triangle $ABC$ the vertex $C$ moves perpendicular to the base $AB$ so that the area of the triangle grows at a speed of $4 cm^2/s$. The base $AB$ is $3 cm$ long.

1. At what rate does the height $CH$ grow?
2. What about the $CB$ side?

I solved the first question using derivatives, knowing that:

- the area of a triangle measures $A =\frac{1}{2} \cdot AB \cdot CH$
- the base stays constant in time

So we get that:
$\frac{dA}{dt} = \frac{3 \ cm}{2} \cdot \frac{dCH}{dt}$

$\frac{dCH}{dt} = 4 \frac{cm^2}{s} \cdot \frac{2}{3 \ cm}$

$\frac{dCH}{dt} = \frac{8 \ cm}{3 \ s}$

For the second question i thought i could use pythogorean theorem on the triangle $CHB$, getting:

$CB = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} {AB}^2 + {CH}^2}$

but im not sure on how to get $\frac{dCB}{dt}$.

Comment: If you differentiate your equation for $CB$ with respect to $t$, and noting that $\dfrac{dAB}{dt}$ is constant, then...

Comment: By the chain rule, $$\frac{dCB}{dt} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac14 AB^2+CH^2}} \cdot \frac{d\left(\frac14 AB^2+CH^2\right)}{dt}$$